# Building sentences

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, auxiliary-verbs

In the sentences below is it mandatory the use of auxiliary-verbs, or they make sense even the manner they are written?

> If your body's temperature falls below 20 degrees centigrade, you die.
>
> If your body's temperature raises above 42 degrees centigrade, you die.

Or without commas:

> If your body's temperature falls below 20 degrees centigrade you die.
>
> If your body's temperature raises above 42 degrees centigrade you die.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're fine without auxiliaries.  Commas are recommended but not strictly required.

You should write *rises* rather than *raises*, though.  There's no direct object here, so the intransitive verb *rise* is more appropriate than transitive verb *raise*.